# How do you use back-references to PCREs in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I read this [PHP RegEx page](http://us.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.php), but either I'm missing something, misreading something, or it doesn't work the way they say. I'm guessing it's one of the first two.

```
$str = preg_replace("([|]\d*)", "\1;", $str);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regular expression should follow Perl syntax, meaning it has to start and end with the same character (with some exceptions). Also, the back reference should start with a double slash, to get around PHPs double escaping. This should work (with a quick test):

```
$str = "asdfasdf |123123 asdf iakds |302 asdf |11";
$str = preg_replace("/([|]\d*)/", "\\1;", $str);
echo $str; // prints "asdfasdf |123123; asdf iakds |302; asdf |11;"
```

Comment: Note that the `$n` backreference syntax is preferred over `\\n`. So says the manual.